# Stratifying SAS health data by age range

Tags: statistics, sas

Here's my dataset

Column 1:
Lipid level

Column 2:
Age

Column 3:
Fat content category

Column 4:
Gender (1=male)

```
   0.73      1      1   1
   0.67      1      2   1
   0.15      1      3   1
   0.86      2      1   1
   0.67      2      2   1
   0.15      2      3   1
   0.94      3      1   1
   0.81      3      2   1
   0.26      3      3   1
   0.23      4      1   2
   1.40      4      1   1
   1.32      4      2   1
   0.15      4      3   1
   1.62      5      1   1
   1.41      5      2   1
   0.78      5      3   1
   9.78      5      1   1
```

Here's a few different analysis I'm running with this code but I'm not so sure why SAS is not compiling.

Before doing anything else, I set up a permanent library manually.

```
libname di ‘c:\diet’;
data di.HW3 Data;
infile hw3 data.sas;
input Lipidlevel Age Fatcontent Gender;
run;
```

Is there any way that I can stratify the data as follows?  I want to create labels and formats for both the Age Group and Fat Content Category variables. The age groups are coded 1 to 5 and correspond to: 15-24; 25-34; 35-44; 45-54; 55-64. The fat content categories are coded 1 to 3 and correspond to: extremely low; fairly low; moderately low.  I have no idea how to do this. The only way I can think of is to go into the original dataset and sort them out manually.

I mean of course if I were given a much larger dataset then it would be impractical to do so.  Can I get some help here?

Comment: Your `INFILE` statement is wrong. Either include a fileref (ie alias) like `hw3` or a physical path like `"data.sas"`, but not both.  Also watch out for those not quote character quotes that WORD or something has generated in your `libname` statement.  SAS does not understand those fancy quotes. Just normal `"` or `'` quotes.

Comment: Are you asking how to create formats for your coded variables (what SPSS would call value labels)?  Use `PROC FORMAT` to create them. You can then use a `FORMAT` statement to tell SAS which formats to use with which variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your coded variables display with descriptive words you should use formats. First define some formats.

```
proc format;
  value agegp 1='15-24' 2='25-34' 3='35-44' 4='45-54' 5='55-64';
  value fat   1='extremely low' 2='fairly low' 3='moderately low';
  vale sex '1'='male' ;
run;
```

You can then attach them to the variables. You can do it in the step that creates the dataset, or just attach them where you want to use them.

```
proc freq data=di.hw3;
  tables age fatcontent gender;
  format age agegp. fatcontent fat. gender sex. ;
run;
```